# Running a command on worker node from master node

Tags: kubernetes, jobs, kubernetes-jobs

I am working with a project which requires to run commands directly on worker nodes (to configure worker nodes) using client-go in kubernetes.
How can I achieve it?

If I create a job, it creates a pod and run the job inside the container which is not what I need.

Comment: Your cluster administrator would need to use an ordinary administration tool to set up the nodes.  You can't directly access the nodes via the Kubernetes API or from inside a Pod.

Comment: Okay. So, what I am trying to achieve is to schedule a custom resource directly on a node (not on a pod). The default k8s-scheduler binds the pod to a node. Can I do the binding of a custom resource to a node, so that custom resource can be deployed on specific node. Does kubernetes provide any API endpoint to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean a Kubernetes custom resource, with a CustomResourceDefinition?  Your controller code can manipulate the resource however it likes, including putting the name of a node in a field, but that wouldn't cause any specific changes on the named host.  There isn't anything in the Kubernetes API that would let you manipulate the hosts outside of the Kubernetes environment.

Comment: Yes, a custom resource through CRD. So, it means I cannot create a binding of a custom resource to node in my custom scheduler. The only binding we can have in kubernetes is the pod to node. Right?

Comment: I can imagine a controller creating custom resources "attached to nodes" in the same way a DaemonSet will create a Pod per node; but a resource having the name of a Node in a field doesn't necessarily mean anything outside of the Kubernetes API layer.

Comment: Yes but at the end daemonset creates the pods and then these pods are scheduled by kube-scheduler. Does mentioning the name of a node in custom resource specs schedule the custom resource onto that node (just like kube-scheduler does for pods)? I think the Kubernetes only supports the scheduling of pods not the scheduling of custom resources.